# caused by: System.SObjectException: Opportunity.AccountId does not belong to SObject type AggregateResult

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I simply wanted to update inserted line item count on Account field Name Line_Item_Counts but ended up with this issue. code is errorless but at the UI I am unable to insert Quoteline Items

Here is the code Im trying to execute.

```java
trigger updateolicount on OpportunityLineItem(after insert) {
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) {
        oppIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);  
    }
    
    oppIds.remove(null);
    
    if (!oppIds.isEmpty()) {
        Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
        
        for (Opportunity oppty : [
            select AccountId
            from Opportunity
            where Id in :oppIds
        ]) {
            accIds.add(oppty.AccountId);
        }   
        
        if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
            List<Account> accToUpdate = new List<Account>();
            List<AggregateResult> aggrs = [SELECT Opportunity.AccountId, count(Id)oli FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                           where Opportunity.AccountId IN:accIds GROUP BY Opportunity.AccountId];
            
            for (AggregateResult ar :aggrs) {
                Decimal total = (decimal)ar.get('oli');
                Id AcctoUpdate =(Id)ar.get(Opportunity.AccountId);
                Account accObj = new Account();
                accObj.Id =AcctoUpdate;
                accObj.Line_Item_Counts__c =total;
                accToUpdate.add(accObj);
            }   
            
            if (!accToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                update accToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone please help me to resolve this issue..Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Opportunity.AccountId
```

Is a [sObjectField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm) token that represents a field. Specifically, it's a field that doesn't exist on `AggregateResult`. Instead, give it an alias, and use that, instead:

```
List<AggregateResult> aggrs = [SELECT Opportunity.AccountId AccountId, count(Id)oli FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                               where Opportunity.AccountId IN:accIds GROUP BY Opportunity.AccountId];
```

```
Id AcctoUpdate =(Id)ar.get('AccountId');
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve any data off an `AggregateResult` using field tokens (`SObjectField`). You must always use a `String` instead. Even if it would work, your field token must actually match the object in your `FROM` clause, which in your case is `OpportunityLineItem`, not `Opportunity`.

**Incorrect:**

```
aggregate.get(Opportunity.AccountId)
```

**Correct:**

```
aggregate.get('expr0');
```

Note that you could alias `Opportunity.AccountId` so it has an easier to use, explicit reference.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using SObject's `.get()` method with an `AggregateResult` (and `AggregateResult` is a subtype of `SObject`), you need to pass it a string containing the field name. Using a field token won't work.

So
`Id AcctoUpdate = (Id)ar.get(Opportunity.AccountId);`
is incorrect, since you aren't passing in a string.

Since you're trying to get data from a *related* record, if you don't use a field alias like sfdcfox's answer, you can't just make `Opportunity.AccountId` into a string. Instead, you'd have to first get the related record using SObject's `.getSObject()` method.

```
// Note that because we're first casting to a concrete SObject type, we can use
//   dot notation after the cast
Id AcctoUpdate = ((Opportunity)ar.getSObject('Opportunity')).AccountId;

// You could also do it as a two-liner
// Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)ar.getSObject('Opportunity');
// Id accToUpdate = opp.AccountId;
```

Aliasing, or using a formula field to pull the AccountId into the OpportunityLineItem records would likely be what you should try before taking this particular approach.